# can findViewById() alternative

Tags: android, view

I need to get all `views` with specified id returned from `activity`. Do I have to walk `View` tree or is there any built-in that returns all occurrences of `views` with specified id?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve a `View` you need to assign it a unique ID by using the `android:id` attribute. If you do not then you will have to an alternative mean which is more tedious, such as parsing the view tree.

The description from [Layouts | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) mentions:

> **ID**
>
> Any View object may have an integer ID associated with it, to uniquely
>   identify the View within the tree. When the application is compiled,
>   this ID is referenced as an integer, but the ID is typically assigned
>   in the layout XML file as a string, in the id attribute. This is an
>   XML attribute common to all View objects (defined by the View class)
>   and you will use it very often. The syntax for an ID, inside an XML
>   tag is:

```
android:id="@+id/my_button"
```

Of relevance to you should also be this quote from the same page:

> An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).

So to find your view, you should use `findViewByID()` less you have to look at the view tree. For an example on how to do that, I recommend you consule [Grokking Android's Finding all View-IDs of an Android UI](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/finding-all-view-ids-of-an-android-ui/)